# If $\{M_n\}$ is a sub-martingale that's bounded, and $\nu, \tau$ are bounded stop times with $\nu \leq \tau$, how to show $E(M_\nu) \leq E(M_\tau)$?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Suppose that $\{M_n\}$ is a submartingale that is bounded and we have that $\nu, \tau$ are bounded stopping times and that $\nu \leq \tau$. I would like to show that $\mathbb{E}(M_\nu) \leq \mathbb{E}(M_\tau)$. I believe that as long as I can create a relation between $M_\tau$ and $M_\nu$ in terms of a new martingale, and show that its positive, I am done. Does anyone have any hints how I can approach this?

Comment: May you use the Optional Sampling theorem for martingales? If yes, then use Doob's decomposition

$$M_n=M_0+V_n+A_n,$$

where $V_n$ is a UI martingale and $A_n$ is an increasing predictable process.

Comment: could you elaborate how you might do this? thanks

Comment: @d.k.o. Can we use $n \to \infty$ in Problem 2 [here](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~nkang/Ma144a/HW3.pdf)?